# Better way than multiple ngIf

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6, angular-ng-if

I want to make my code shorter so it could be readable. I have a multiple ngIf with different conditions for a numbering order of a list (eg 1, 1.1 , 1.1.1)

Here is my code at template side

```
<span *ngIf="types.inputs.length > 1 && inputs.input.length > 1 && inputs.hasMultipleInput == true && inputs.hasMultipleSummaries == false && input.designSummaries.length == 1">{{in+1}}.{{inp+1}}. ({{sum.summary}})</span>
<span *ngIf="types.inputs.length > 1 && inputs.input.length > 1 && inputs.hasMultipleInput == true && inputs.hasMultipleSummaries == true && input.designSummaries.length == 1">{{in+1}}.{{inp+1}}.{{s+1}} ({{sum.summary}})</span>
<span *ngIf="types.inputs.length > 1 && types.hasMultipleInputs == true && inputs.input.length == 1 && input.designSummaries.length == 1">{{in+1}}.{{inp+1}}. ({{sum.summary}})</span>
<span *ngIf="types.inputs.length > 1 && types.hasMultipleInputs == false && inputs.input.length == 1 && input.designSummaries.length == 1">{{in+1}}. ({{sum.summary}})</span>
<span *ngIf="types.inputs.length > 1 && types.hasMultipleInputs == true && inputs.input.length == 1 && input.designSummaries.length > 1">{{in+1}}.{{inp+1}}.{{s+1}}. ({{sum.summary}})</span>
<span *ngIf="types.inputs.length > 1 && types.hasMultipleInputs == false && inputs.input.length == 1 && input.designSummaries.length > 1">{{in+1}}.{{s+1}}. ({{sum.summary}})</span>
<span *ngIf="types.inputs.length == 1 && inputs.input.length > 1 && input.designSummaries.length > 1">{{inp+1}}.{{s+1}}. ({{sum.summary}})</span>
<span *ngIf="types.inputs.length > 1 && inputs.input.length > 1 && input.designSummaries.length > 1">{{in+1}}.{{inp+1}}.{{s+1}}. ({{sum.summary}})</span>
<span *ngIf="types.inputs.length == 1 && inputs.input.length > 1 && input.designSummaries.length == 1">{{inp+1}}. ({{sum.summary}})</span>
<span *ngIf="types.inputs.length == 1 && inputs.input.length == 1 && input.designSummaries.length > 1">{{s+1}}. ({{sum.summary}})</span>
<span *ngIf="types.inputs.length == 1 && inputs.input.length == 1 && input.designSummaries.length == 1">({{sum.summary}})</span>
```

This will be repeated in other column and with some additonal interpolation and i just dont want to use this long code in my entire project.

I just want any suggestions from you guys :)

[My code on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8ngzhl)

Comment: Will *ngSwitch help you? Check out the doc https://angular.io/api/common/NgSwitch

Comment: dont know if NgSwitch will work since i got many conditions but will try it :)

Comment: Consider using independent `<span>` elements for `{{in+1}}`, `{{inp+1}}`, and `{{s+1}}`, each with its own `ngIf` condition (which will hopefully be simpler than the pile of conditions you have now).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should **put all your logic in a method** (let's say `getNumberingOrder()`) that returns the desired `string` and simply display it with : `<span>{{getNumberingOrder()}}</span>`.

*Of course, you will pass parameters to this function.*

Comment: took me 3hrs to accept. sorry for that got lost my connection

thank you for the better answer :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`ngSwitch`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgSwitch), do function to return a ngSwithcase value

```
<div [ngSwitch]="hero?.emotion">
  <app-happy-hero    *ngSwitchCase="'happy'"    [hero]="hero"></app-happy-hero>
  <app-sad-hero      *ngSwitchCase="'sad'"      [hero]="hero"></app-sad-hero>
  <app-confused-hero *ngSwitchCase="'app-confused'" [hero]="hero"></app-confused-hero>
  <app-unknown-hero  *ngSwitchDefault           [hero]="hero"></app-unknown-hero>
</div>
```